# How to use relative paths in a Qt-based Autodesk Maya plug-in?

Tags: c++, qt, maya

I'm trying to build a plug-in for Maya 2016 using Qt and I'm not sure how to use a relative path to reference a specific asset I need.

Inside my code for my plug-in, I'm using `QUiLoader` and `QFile` to load a `my_ui.ui` file which contains my pre-designed dialog window made from Qt Designer:

```
QUiLoader   loader;
QFile       file("my_ui.ui");

file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
fForm = loader.load(&file, this);
file.close();
```

The `my_ui.ui` is in the same directory as my compiled `plugin.so` plug-in (I'm using Linux).

Any sort of relative pathing (`./`, `.`) gives me the location to wherever Maya is ran from, understandably. But is there a way to get the path of my `.so` plugin itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution on my own:

In my Qt Project `.pro` file, I added the following lines:

```
FORMS += my_ui.ui
RESOURCES += my_ui.qrc
```

And I added a new file, `my_ui.qrc`, which contained this:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>my_ui.ui</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

The `.qrc` resource collection file lists the dependencies of my application, and adding the `RESOURCES` line to my `.pro` file tells qmake to compile my resource files into the final binary.

Then in my application, I modified my QFile constructor to use the resource path:

```
QFile       file(":/my_ui.ui");
```

I got this info from looking at the Maya devkit Qt examples and the Qt Resource System documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Comment: They do exactly what you said: the file is embedded in the plugin, and `QFile` implements a virtual file system that redirects to the embedded file when given proper path.

Comment: @KubaOber Thought so, I looked at the Qt Resource System documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) and that gave me the detailed info I was looking for. Thanks.